# Field is not inserting in Table

Tags: php

I have a sql but one thing is not inserting and that is the 'name' field (username)

My SQL code:

```
$serverdb->query("INSERT INTO cms_users
                (
                  name,lastvisit,online,ipaddress_last,newsletter,email_verified,
                  show_home,email_friendrequest,email_minimail,email,show_online)
                 VALUES    
                (
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string($row[1])."','".time()."','".time()."',
                 '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','1','1','1','1','1','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."','1')"
                 ) 
              or die (mysql_error()
    );
```

My website is not giving a error or something, its inserting this sql without a username. (btw, this is for a register page)

Comment: You checked already if the `$row` has value? Try use `print_r($row)` to see the content

Comment: It does not have a value, how can i set a value? I'm not good at sqls. @Bruzetti

Comment: include the code where you assign `$row` ?

Comment: what is $row? Try posting your whole code!

Comment: I believe the value of `$email` came from a form, right? If the form have the `name` field, just do the same thing and replace `$row[1]` to `$name`. It's hard to know without see the whole code.

Comment: @Bruzetti I have in my form this: 

<label for="username-address">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="username-address" name="bean.name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['bean_name'])){ echo $_POST['bean_name']; } else { echo $_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_name']; }?>" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['quickregister']['state1'])) { echo 'class="error"'; unset($_SESSION['quickregister']['state1']);} else { }?> /> Can you post the whole sql how i need to replace it? I'm not good in to edit sqls.

Comment: Try replace the `$rows[1]` to `$_POST['bean_name']`.

Comment: I already have a filter on bean_name above my code.  
$username = $db->escape_string($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_name']); Can you make the sql code without mysql filter?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i have understood your problem very well but it seems that one of your problems is that you have mispelled the name attribute in your html form.

```
name="bean.name"
```

It should be

```
name="bean_name"
```

So $_POST['bean_name'] is always empty.

What is your code that fetches the row from your database?

Another issue is the use of mysql_* functions because they are deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). For security reasons try to use PDO or something similar.

Comment: I have changed that but the field name is still empty?

Comment: Check what happens if you hardcoded the sql query using a string for the name column. Instead of:  '".mysql_real_escape_string($row[1])."' use a string like: 'my_fixed_name'. 
Also, check if name column is the second column in the query that fetches the $row otherwise maby this is the reason it is empty.

Comment: I have in my table ID first, but this is a auto increment. Can you edit my sql code that name will be the second? I'm not good at sqls at all. @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: Using mysql_* functions you have to use something like this to fetch the row:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM table_1 WHERE id = '100' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];