# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 (Help needed )

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error on my register page. I'm trying to resolve this now for 2 hours, but it still isn't fixed.

My php code:

```
<?php
define('SSL', true);
$page['dir'] = '\quickregister';
require_once('../includes/core.php');
require_once('./includes/recaptchalib.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: ".PATH."/me");
    exit;
}

ini_set("display_errors", 1);


$data = new register_sql;
$captchaResponse = $input->FilterText($_POST['captchaResponse']);
$privatekey = "THIS IS AN ULTRA SECRET KEY I SHOULD NOT SHARE, I SHOULD TREAT IS AS A PASSWORD";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $captchaResponse);

if(!$resp->is_valid) 
    {
        $error = "De code die je in hebt getypt is ongeldig. Probeer het nog eens.";
    }
$espacios = count_chars(@$_POST['bean_name'], 1);
$name = $input->FilterText($_POST['bean_name']);
$filter = preg_replace("/[^a-z\d\-=\?!@:\_]/i", "", $name);
if($user->validName($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_name']))
    {
        $Errorz .= 'De naam die je gebruikt is verboden.';
        $State = 1;
    }
else
    if(!empty($espacios[32]))
        {
            $Errorz .= 'De naam mag geen spaties bevatten.';
            $State = 1;
        }

if($filter != $name){
    $Error .= 'Deze Spacenaam is niet toegestaan<br />';
    $State = 1;
}
if(strlen($_POST['bean_name']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['bean_name']) >= 40)
    {
        $Error .= 'Je Space naam is te lang of te kort.<br />';
        $State = 1; }

else
    if($user->NameTaken($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_name']))
        {
            $Errorz .= "Deze naam is al ingebruik.";
            $State = 1;
        }
    else
        if($user->EmailTaken($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_email']))
            {
                header("Location: ".PATH."/quickregister/duplicateEmailLogin");
                exit;
            }
        else
            if(!$user->validar_email($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_email']))
                {
                    $Errorz .= 'De e-mail die je hebt ingevoerd is ongeldig.';
                    $State2 = 1;
                } 
            else
                if($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_email'] !== $_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_retypedEmail'])
                    {
                        $Errorz .= 'De e-mails komen niet overeen. Zorg ervoor dat ze hetzelfde zijn.';
                        $State2 = 1;
                        $State3 = 1;
                    }
                else
                    if(strlen($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_password']) < 6 || strlen($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_password']) >= 40)
                        {
                            $Errorz .= 'Het wachtwoord moet minstens 6 karakters zijn.';
                            $State4 = 1;
                        }
if(isset($Errorz))
    {
        $_SESSION['quickregister']['error'] = $Errorz;
        unset($_SESSION['quickregister']['email_pass']);
        $_SESSION['quickregister']['age_gate'] = true;
        header("Location: ".PATH."/quickregister/email_password");
    }
if($error == null)
    {
        $_SESSION['PHP_CONECT'] = "habbo";
        $username = $db->escape_string($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_name']);
        $password = $input->HoloHash($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_password'], $username);
        $look = $input->FilterText($_POST['bean_figure']);
        $email = $db->escape_string($_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_email']);
        $gender = $_SESSION['quickregister']['gender'];
        $birth = $_SESSION['quickregister']['bean_birth'];
        $birth = explode('-', $birth2);
        $birth2 = $birth2[2].'-'.$birth2[1].'-'.$birth[0];
        $scredits = "450000";
        $pixels = "6000";
        $motto = "Welkom!";
        $data->insert1($username,$password,$birth,$look,$motto,$gender,$scredits,$email,$pixels);
        $row = $serverdb->fetch_row($data->select3($username));

        $serverdb->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."users (id,name,lastvisit,online,ipaddress_last,newsletter,email_verified,show_home,email_friendrequest,email_minimail,email,show_online) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".time()."','".time()."','".$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]."','1','1','1','1','1','".$email."','1')") or die (mysql_error());


        $hash = "";
        $length = 8;
        $possible = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjkzxcvbnm";
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $length) {
            $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            if (!strstr($hash, $char)) {
                $hash .= $char;
                $i++;
            }}
        $hash = sha1($hash);
        $num = $key;
        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."verify (id,email,key_hash) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$email."','".$hash."')");
        $subject = "Welkom in ".SHORTNAME;
        $to = $email;
        $html = 
            '<html><head><style type="text/css">
    a { color: #fc6204; }
    </style></head>
    <body style="background-color: #e3e3db; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000;">

    <div style="background-color: #bce0ee; padding: 14px; border-bottom: 3px solid #000;">
        <img src="cid:habbologo" alt="http://yabsoon.nl" />
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 14px 14px 50px 14px; background-color: #e3e3db;">
        <div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 14px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
        <h1 style="font-size: 16px"><font color="black"><b>Beste '.$row[1].',</b></font></h1>

        <p>
        Het is belangerijk dat je bevestigt dat dit e-mail addres van jou is, <br />
    Klik op de volgende link om jou Space account te activeren: <a href="'.PATH.'/email?key='.$hash.'">'.$lang->loc['email.verify.2.b'].'</a>
        </p>
        <p>
        Bewaar de volgende gegevens veilig:
        </p>
        <p>
        <b>'.$lang->loc['email.verify.4'].'</b> '.$row[1].'<br>
        <b>'.$lang->loc['email.verify.5'].'</b> '.$birth.'
        </p>

        <p>
        Heb je je niet geregistreerd op Yabsoon? Klik dan <a href="'.PATH.'/email?remove='.$hash.'">hier!</a>
        </p>


        </div>
        <div style="padding: 14px 0; text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                Copyright © 2006-2012 Space hotel. Alle rechten voorbehouden.
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>';


        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."homes (ownerid,itemid,x,y,z,skin,location) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','220','252','12','66','defaultskin','0')");
        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."homes (ownerid,itemid,x,y,z,skin,location) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','10400','38','263','88','defaultskin','0')");
        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."homes (ownerid,itemid,x,y,z,skin,location) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','10600','59','646','103','defaultskin','0')");
        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."homes (ownerid,itemid,x,y,z,skin,location) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','10100','437','29','79','defaultskin','0')");
        $db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."homes (ownerid,itemid,x,y,z,skin,location) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','10700','438','262','83','defaultskin','0')");

        unset($_SESSION['quickregister']);
        $user = new HoloUser($username,$password,true);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

        header("Location: ".PATH."/security_check");

        exit;

    }
else{
    $_SESSION['quickregister']['error'] = $error;
    header('Location: '.PATHSECURE.'/quickregister/captcha');
    exit;
}
?>
```

I get this error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 Does someone know what i do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please be sure to strip all code from sensitive info such as passwords and private keys.

Comment: Its just a captcha key @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable

Comment: Check your sql. You are using a string where you need a number.

Comment: @JasonK I do not see it, where i'm using a string?

Comment: The problem isn't that he's using a string, because MySQL will convert strings to numbers. The problem is that the string is **empty**, so it's not a valid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment yet so i will post it here. I think that problem lies on the following lines:

```
$data->insert1($username,$password,$birth,$look,$motto,$gender,$scredits,$email,$pixels);
$row = $serverdb->fetch_row($data->select3($username));
```

Check what's inside $row and tell us.

```
var_dump($row);
```

UPDATE

After many comments, we found out that the problem was that the id column at table "users" had to change to auto_increment. Also, in "insert1" function was missing some single quotes on a insert query column.

Comment: Did that make any difference? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912398/field-is-not-inserting-in-table/32912950#32912950

Comment: This is $row 

 function select3($name){
  $sql = $GLOBALS['serverdb']->query("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE username = '".$name."' LIMIT 1");
  return $sql;
 } @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: It is very important to show us the results of var_dump($row) because there are two possibilities:

A) 
$data->insert1($username,$password,$birth,$look,$motto,$gender,$scredits,$email,$pixels);

doesn't insert nothing

B) 
$serverdb->fetch_row($data->select3($username));

doesn't return nothing

Comment: Where in my sql need to implent the var_dump($row) ? @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: After $row = $serverdb->fetch_row($data->select3($username)); write the following: var_dump($row); exit;

Comment: I have did it. Now i get this on my page: bool(false) @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: It means no data was returned and most likely your insert on the previous line failed.

Comment: Ok. That means that $row is empty so there are no $row[0] and $row[1] values to be used for the next insertion. Can u show us the code of function: insert1($username,$password,$birth,$look,$motto,$gender,$scredits,$email,$pixels) ?

Comment: This is the insert1. I have uploaded it on pastebin, because it was too long for stackoverflow: http://pastebin.com/HtQw7Kc5   @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: Ok. Now after $user_id = mysql_insert_id(); write: var_dump($user_id); exit; and tell us the results;

Comment: Now it says on the page: int(0) @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: That means that the insertion $GLOBALS['serverdb']->query("INSERT INTO users (username.........); didn't happened. Comment out $GLOBALS['serverdb']->query("INSERT.....") and instead try: mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, mail, credits, activity_points, look, motto, account_created, last_online, ip_last, ip_reg, home_room, birth) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$password."', '".$email."', ".$scredits.", '".$pixels."', '".$figure."', '".$motto."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '0', '".$dob."')");

Comment: I have replaced it but i get still int(0) and when i remove the var_dump i get the same error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1. @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: replace ".$scredits." with '".$scredits."' and try again (single quotes missing).

Comment: I have copyed your code: http://pastebin.com/yC7TqpuS  @KostasMitsarakis Still get int(0).

Comment: Use:

$GLOBALS['serverdb']->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, mail, credits, activity_points, look, motto, account_created, last_online, ip_last, ip_reg, home_room, birth) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$password."', '".$email."',  '".$scredits."', '".$pixels."', '".$figure."', '".$motto."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '0', '".$dob."')");

Comment: Also you don't use $gender in the query. Is it a required column?

Comment: No its not required @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: Write right after the query the following:
echo mysql_error();
exit;

What is the output?

Comment: Now its says: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1.

Comment: Check if id column in users table is set to auto_increment.

Comment: thanks its solved!! God bless you :) @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: I had to think of it earlier. But i am glad i helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string where you need a number. remove the single quotes around the row[0]

You have

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."verify (id,email,key_hash) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$email."','".$hash."')");
```

It should be

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."verify (id,email,key_hash) VALUES (".$row[0].",'".$email."','".$hash."')");
```

You have this in multiple places. You should also be using prepared statements you are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert strings to numbers when inserting.

Comment: $serverdb->query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."users (id,name,lastvisit,online,ipaddress_last,newsletter,email_verified,show_home,email_friendrequest,email_minimail,email,show_online) VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".time()."','".time()."','".$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]."','1','1','1','1','1','".$email."','1')") or die (mysql_error());
 There is something wrong in this sql, can you fix @Barmar ?

Comment: @ShredderReal The error is complaining that `$row[0]` is empty. That's coming from `$serverdb->fetch_row($data->select3($username));`, I don't know what that does.

Comment: Echo out the first sql so we can see what is actually being sent.